# Product Thumbnails Showing up in Admin but not Frontend

Tags: magento2.3, product-images, thumbnail, category-image, not-showing

I have small_image, thumbnail and base assigned for our product thumbnail images in the admin (which are visible there) which should be showing up on the frontend category pages. The placeholder images are being used instead. I gave the pub/media folder 777 permissions, flushed every cache despite being in developer mode and caching is disabled and that didn't work. I ran php bin/magento catalog:image:resize and received this error:

magento2/pub/media/catalog/product/b/f/bf-cover-fan.png" - original image not found

But the image is there:
[image]

I am using the Mirasvit Optimiztion extension that does a number of optimization tasks like: makes webp images from jpgs and png, minimized JS and CSS etc...so not sure if this might be causing the issue as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the possibilities:

Possible reason 1: You have wrong permissions on your /media/ folder

Possible reason 2: Media folder is owned by another user.

Possible reason 3: There’s an issue with the .htaccess file in your /media/ folder

Possible reason 4: Magento cannot resize images due low PHP memory limit.

Possible reason 5: The GD library is not installed/configured

Possible reason 6: Wrong attribute scope for small_image, thumbnail, base_image